# Display item in Marionette CollectionView that's not member of the collection?

Tags: marionette

I have a Marionette CollectionView where each of the childViews are floating in a grid fashion (where each X is a childView):

```
X X X X
X X X
```

I'd like to have a plus button that is floating in the grid as well but won't actually be representing an item in the collection. So it would look like this:

```
X X X X
X X X +
```

Does anyone have an idea or strategy for how this could be done with Marionette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do exactly this in our app. To achieve it we have a composite view with a template like:

```
<div class='my-composite-view'>
  <div class='my-child-view-container'>
  </div>
  <div class='my-plus-button'>
  </div>
</div>
```

As long as you float all the divs in the `my-child-view-container` and then float the `my-plus-button` div as well you will get exactly what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/cn1gp4m4/

Answer (score 1):

While you might add the html element manually, this is where I would move to [CompositeView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.compositeview.html) if I needed to display anything except the collection in the view. CompositeView would maintain the collection view in a given container within a template, so you could have any elements in the same view with the collection.

But CompositeView will not allow you to have other elements within the collection container as a sibling to the collection view items. If you really need your own element as a sibling to the collection view items, you can add it manually as I show below. But I would definitely go with CompositeView to keep the html structure clean.

This example shows that you can actually add the element manually, position it with CSS however you want. Marionette will not remove your manually-added element, because it doesn't really re-render itself, it simply adds and removes the child views when they are added or removed from the collection.

```js
var ItemView = Mn.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('<%=title%> (<a href="#">remove</a>)'),
  events: { 'click a': 'rm' },
  rm: function(evt){
    this.model.collection.remove( this.model );
  }
});

var col = new Backbone.Collection([
  {title: 'Espresso'},
  {title: 'Cappuccino'},
  {title: 'Caffe Latte'}
]);
col.counter = 0;

var colview = new Mn.CollectionView({
  collection: col,
  className: 'Collection',
  childView: ItemView
});

var $add = $('<div class="add">+</div>').click(function(){
  col.add({ title: 'Coffee #'+(++col.counter) });
});
colview.$el.append($add);

colview.render().$el.appendTo(document.body);

col.add({title:'Americano'});
col.remove( col.at(1) );
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.Collection {
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.add {
  border-color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #888;
  text-align: center;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.4.3/backbone.marionette.js'></script>
```

#### Update

In an updated example we extend CollectionView to add our custom element on render, and override internal `_insertAfter` method to add new elements just before our element, instead of appending it at the end of the container.

```js
var CollectionView = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
  _insertAfter: function(childView){
    this.$add.before( childView.el );
  },
  onRender: function(){
    this.$add = $('<div class="add">+</div>').click(function(){
      col.add({ title: 'Coffee #'+(++col.counter) });
    }).appendTo( this.el );
  }
});

var ItemView = Mn.ItemView.extend({
  template: _.template('<%=title%> (<a href="#">remove</a>)'),
  events: { 'click a': 'rm' },
  rm: function(evt){
    this.model.collection.remove( this.model );
  }
});

var col = new Backbone.Collection([
  {title: 'Espresso'},
  {title: 'Cappuccino'},
  {title: 'Caffe Latte'}
]);
col.counter = 0;

var colview = new CollectionView({
  collection: col,
  className: 'Collection',
  childView: ItemView
});

colview.render().$el.appendTo(document.body);

col.add({title:'Americano'});
col.remove( col.at(1) );
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.Collection {
  border-color: red;
}
.add {
  border-color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #888;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.4.3/backbone.marionette.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - a couple problems: I can't use flexbox for compatibility reasons and I need the elements to float so the + would have to be in the container but this points me in the right direction. Also, we are looking for a strong javascript developer w/ Marionette experience. Are you potentially looking for a job?

Comment: Flexbox is just an example styling, but if you really need to also have the custom element stay as the last sibling, you would also have to override [`attachHtml`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-attachhtml) method. I'll see if I can add another example for that. Also you can contact me at `yuraji at gmail`.

Comment: Added second example which doesn't use styling for positioning - our custom element is always the last sibling of the collection child views.